# Marshalls fought in the Spanish Civil War

Tags: military-records, ireland, 1930s, spain

I am trying to find out if I am related to Marshalls who fought in the Spanish Civil War.  There were Marshalls killed in battle outside Madrid.

Comment: Hi, Tina -- I've removed identifying information for live people as per our site privacy policy.

Comment: Do you have anything other than a name coincidence to work from -- if you have more info you can share with us about why you believe there might be a link (and what information you've already looked ofr?)

Comment: What record(s) have you found to support your statement that "There were Marshalls killed in battle outside Madrid"?